# Bounded sequence and inf problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence. Prove that for any $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists an N such that for n $\geq$ N, 
$$x_n > \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf x_n - \epsilon$$
Hint: recall that $\lim \inf x_n$ = $\lim a_n$, where $a_n = \inf{x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},...}$. First show the inequality above for $a_n$, and then conclude it for $x_n$.

I don't get why the hint is useful, I see the definition of convergence in the first line but
that's about the only thing I recognize besides that I don't understand why $\inf$ is involved.

Comment: Clean the notation up by letting $\ell$ stand for the limit infimum of the sequence in question, and $A_N = \{x_n | n \geqslant N\}$ for $N = 1,2,3,...$. You should feel confident that $a_N = \inf A_N \nearrow \ell$ as $N \to \infty$. This is a matter of definition. For such convergence to be possible it must be true that $a_N > \ell - \varepsilon$ for some $N$ (this inequality will hold for many, many indexes $N$ but all we need is one), and for such an $N$ we have that $n \geqslant N \Longrightarrow x_n \in A_N \Longrightarrow x_n \geqslant \inf A_N = a_N > \ell - \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

since $y_n:=\inf_{k\geq n}x_k$ is a increasing sequence, $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }x_n:=\lim_{n\to \infty }y_n=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}y_n.$$

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. By definition of the supremum, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }x_n-\varepsilon <y_N.$$
Therefore, $$\liminf_{n\to \infty }x_n-\varepsilon <x_n$$
for all $n\geq N$.